# understanding angular track by to update specific row

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to understand if track by in angular is the correct approach for me.  I have an array of objects that I need to display.  One of the columns is the unique identifier so this is what I have.

```
   <tr ng-repeat="person in allPeople track by person.ssn">
    </tr>
```

Now what I'm trying to understand is, can I update just one row based on the ssn?  If not, what the advantage of track by here?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

For updating a row based on the ssn .Follow this link 
[How to update only specific rows when using ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648501/how-to-update-only-specific-rows-when-using-ng-repeat)

The default tracking function (which tracks items by their identity) does not allow duplicate items in arrays. This is because when there are duplicates, it is not possible to maintain a one-to-one mapping between collection items and DOM elements.

If you do need to repeat duplicate items, you can substitute the default tracking behavior with your own using the track by expression.

For example, you may track items by the index of each item in the collection, using the special scope property $index:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in [42, 42, 43, 43] track by $index">
  {{n}}
</div>
```

For more detail read [the full documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

Comment: I don't understand why you give a down vote as track by is used to iterate over duplicate value which is an advantage as you asked for. But If you are using a ssn then it is a unique number and you can update one row based on it. So, Why down vote my solution..

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  How do I update a specific row if I have the ssn?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope that will help you out.